# how to increase the desire to see Allah's face?

Tags: allah, jannah

As is well known, seeing the face of Allah is the greatest joy, more than the pleasure in heaven.  But in living this world, the desire to see Allah's face often fades.  So is there a way to increase that desire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get closer to God
2. Read more Quran
3. Draw yourself closer to Islam
4. Listen to lectures
5. Form a closer bond with Allah. The closer you are with Him, the more you’d feel attached and inclined to know more about Him.

That’s what I’d advise.

In paradise, you’ll have that feeling no matter what to see Allah. There’s no denying it. I mean, who wouldn’t be curious to see what their lord looks like. It’s a grand honor.

Comment: sadly, it's the curiosity that I feel is disappearing from me. So, I hope read Quran frequently can increase it. thanks.